# Setting desktop backgrounds via Azure Storage Containers using PowerShell not working

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell, intune

I'm trying to set desktop backgrounds for our users from Azure Storage using a PS script I'm hoping to deploy.

[This script](https://github.com/MSEndpointMgr/Intune/blob/master/Customization/Set-WindowsDesktopWallpaper.ps1)

It just isn't working!

For whatever reason, the script just stops calling at a certain point (line 142 onwards) and I can't work out why.
I've added Write-Hosts at certain points to see where it's getting to and it seems to be that return $Bloblist which doesn't run or go any further.

I can see from the logs that it's showing 'Adding content file from Azure Storage Blob to return list: Background-01.png' etc., but that's it. This tells me that is not a permission error as it is looking where it needs to.

I just can't work out why it's not returning that Bloblist.

If anyone could help that'd be super, as we need to change the desktop backgrounds for every user in the company due to a company name change.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (probably) not with the script. The problem is likely due to a setup misstep.

You need to debug the code and find out where it's failing to do what you expect.

You could try [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/debugging-powershell-script-in-visual-studio-code-part-1/) or if videos are your thing you could try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2Rl5GxAzv4).

Comment: I know... as I said it's failing at line 142 but not giving me any error messages in the log - it just stops

Comment: remove the `| Out-Null` from line 137. It's swallowing your output.